# Pass value from lookupfield on VF page to extension

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an email page that uses the "Quote" standard controller. 
 I have an email "To" field where I want user to select the contact (lookupfield) and then it should show the email under "email address" outputfield, but its not working. 
Below is VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="email_class">
<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Email Details" id="ed">
        <b>To: </b> <apex:inputfield value="{!quote.contactid}"/><p/>

     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!Contactpopulated}"   rerender="ed"/>  

     <b>Email address: </b> <apex:outputfield value="{!con.email}"/><p/>
```

and this is the extension:

```
public class email_class{

    Public string ToAddresses {get;set;}
    Public string CCAddresses {get;set;}
    Public string quoteId {get;set;}
    Public string subject {get;set;}
    public string email_body {get;set;}
    public string emailTo {get;set;}
    public string emailCC {get;set;}
    public  string [] ccaddress; 
    public contact con {get;set;}

    private apexpages.standardcontroller stdctrl; 

    public email_class(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
                stdctrl=controller;
                 quoteId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    }

    public void Contactpopulated(){
           quote qte= (Quote)stdctrl.getRecord();
          // qte.contact=[select contact.email from Contact where id=:qte.contactid];
           con=[Select email, name from contact where id=:qte.contactid limit 1];
           system.debug('**************'+ qte.contactid);
          // emailTo= qte.contact.email;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this following method change `Contact` to `ct`

```
public void Contactpopulated(){
       q.ct=[ Select id, email, name From contact where  id=:q.contactid limit 1]; 
}
```

In the visualforce page change this line as follows because you creating an instance of Contact with `ct` variable:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!q.ct.email}"/><p/>
```

Comment: You need to use outputText

Comment: I tried that as well. No luck. I cannot get the email field to update....also why doesnt my   `system.debug('**************'+ qte.contactid);` show up in the log...please help !

Comment: Did my answer ever helped to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `<apex:inputField>` wasnt wrapped around the `<apex:actionsupport>` tag. Doing so fixed my issue:

```
<apex:inputField ...>
    <apex:actionSupport ... />
</apex:inputField>
```